# How can I show p:confirmDialog from bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, confirm-dialog

I got this from primefaces but I dont want to use the button and call the confirm dialog from the bean, how can I do this or render commandbutton and execute from bean?

The problem is that Im using a commandbutton to execute a method, this method has an if in it when true then I want to show a confirm dialog.

```
<p:commandButton value="Destroy the World" actionListener="#{dialogView.destroyWorld}" update="message">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: The confirm dialog is for the direct client-side usage. If you want to have a server side initiated 'confirm', then use a normal dialog. Just do not submit anything when clicking the first button and do when you click the button in the normal dialog that is opened from the server. Not sure what the advantage is though...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do the following

```
 <p:commandButton value="Destroy the World" onclick="PF('confirmDialogwidget').show();">
 </p:commandButton>



<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" header="Are you sure?"
                     widgetVar="confirmDialogwidget">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" 
                     onclick="PF('confirmDialogwidget').hide();" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

or also using bean

```
<p:commandButton value="Destroy the World" actionListener="#{dialogView.destroyWorld}">
</p:commandButton>


<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" header="Are you sure?"
                 widgetVar="confirmDialogwidget">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" 
                     onclick="PF('confirmDialogwidget').hide();"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Here it opens from the bean

```
 public void destroyWorld(){
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('confirmDialogwidget').show();")
}
```

Comment: The method execute(String) from the type RequestContext is deprecated, should I use PrimeFaces current = PrimeFaces.current();
   current.executeScript("PF('confirmDialogwidget').show();");

Comment: What version of primefaces do you use? I use the 6.1 in that version is not deprecated.

Comment: `PrimeFaces current = PrimeFaces.current(); current.executeScript("PF('confirmDialogwidget').show();");`  solve your problem?

Comment: but you need to be able to call the confirmDialog from the bean?

Comment: yes I make a existById query and if its true i want to ask the user if he wants to make an update in database

Comment: Okay, I'm glad to help. Don't forget to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Downvoted this answer as it is as it stands NOT a solution. And even with the suggestion to just change to a normal `p:dialog` (like earlier in my comment) is **not sufficient**